# AC Gearmotor 115 Nameplate RPM 4.0 RPM Max. Torque 75.0 in-lb trips breaker when switch is turned off

Tags: wiring

[image]To whom it may concern, I recently purchased a Dayton AC Gearmotor 115 Nameplate RPM 4.0 RPM Max Model #
52JE07. Torque 75.0 in-lb. The gear motor is single phase with two wires L1 and L2 respectively with no ground. I wired this into a 20 amp industrial switch. From the switch is 10 feet of 14 gauge extension cord to plug to my outlet. When I turn the switch to off, it blows the 20 Amp circuit breaker in my box every time. This motor does not require a capacitor according to the technical specs provided by Dayton. I did not ground the plug nor the switch as the motor is two wire. I switched neutral and hot on the switch and vice versa from the L1 and L2 terminals with absolutely no change.  There are GFCI outlets in the circuit where I am plugging into. They do not trip, only the main breaker. I can turn the motor off and on by tripping the GFCI breaker on the next outlet leaving the switch on. As soon as I turn the switch off, trips the breaker. My question is, should I wire ground to neutral on the switch from my plug wire? Any ideas of what could be causing this?

Comment: please draw a diagram of the electrical connections

Comment: Why are the connections labeled L1 and L2 given this is a 115 V AC motor?

Comment: Jim, I honestly do not know why they labeled them L1 and L2 on this 115 AC motor. Here is a link with Daytons basic drawing.  https://www.grainger.com/ec/pdf/1MBF3_4.pdf

Comment: Did you try hooking it up without the switch?

Comment: Is the circuit breaker a GFCI breaker, or is it a plain breaker?  Does it have a TEST button?  Or is it an AFCI breaker?

Comment: Did you try hooking it up without the switch? I did not previously wire it without a switch.

Comment: Is the circuit breaker a GFCI breaker, or is it a plain breaker? Does it have a TEST button? Or is it an AFCI breaker? – Harper - Reinstate Monica They are AFCI breakers.

Answer (score 4):

I'm pretty sure you wired your switch wrong, and "off" (so you think) is a dead short.